# ZMQ Random Delay/Latency

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq, czmq

I am trying to achieve consistent <500 us latency on my ZMQ REQ/REP application. However, I've encountered 2 types of delay.

- First packet delay : It varies between 5-6ms levels.
- Random delays : It happens randomly(every 5-10s) and varies between 1-8 ms.

I can partially understand the first packet delay since initial connection procedures etc. However, I can't understand the random delay. For context on the problem, my application only has 1 server and 1 client. The client and server run on my local. I developed it in C++. I am trying to understand whether REQ/REP is suitable for my case or if I am missing something. I wrote a sample python script to replicate the problem. Python code is given below,

---

Client

```
import zmq
import time
from random import randbytes

port = "5556"

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)

val = randbytes(200000)

while True:
    st = time.time()
    message = socket.send(val)
    socket.recv()
    ed = time.time()
    took = (ed - st)*1000000 # us
    if took > 400:
        print(took)
```

---

Server

```
import zmq
import time

port = "5556"

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

while True:
    st = time.time()
    message = socket.recv()
    socket.send(b"World from")
    ed = time.time()
    took = (ed - st)*1000000 #us
    if took > 200:
        print(took)
```

**What I've tried**

- different patterns such as lazy pirate etc.
- adding timeouts
- recv pollouts
- increasing number of I/O threads in context

Has anyone encountered something similar?

Note: This problem is not related to hardware. I've tried it on different hardware. If your results are different than mine, please let me know.

**Update:** I have done the same benchmark with boost asio TCP sockets. It performed very well. The average latency was 14us. Used this [repo](https://github.com/farnyser/cpp-ping-pong) for the benchmark. Sent the same amount of data. I think it's safe to say that if multicast is not needed, stick to the POSIX sockets.

**Update 2:** Tested perf [tool](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/tree/master/perf) provided by libzmq. It performed better. The perf tool was measuring the average latency. I added a per-packet latency calculation. For 200Kb data, the average latency was 30us. However, latency was varying between 100us to 2200us(First packet).

**Update 3:** I have more insights now. This random delay is probably caused by the TCP buffers. Since my packet size is big, it creates latency in the long run.